# Pulling my hair with this Syntax Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I seem to be running into a query syntax error but cannot seem to isolate it.  I am using MS Access and when I run the queries I get a syntax error in FROM clause.

I have two tables and they are in a one to many relationship:

Table 1 called (customer) with the following fields:

```
ID
FirstName
```

Table 2 called  (tblservice) with the following fields:

```
serviceID
Timing
Total
customerID   <-Foreign Key
```

First Query:

```
select c.id, c.firstname, avg(s.Total) / (select count(id) from customer) as LifetimeValue
from tblservice as s join customer as c on s.id = c.id
group by s.id
```

Second Query(30 day span):

```
select c.id, c.firstname, avg(s.Total) / (select count(id) from customer) as LifetimeValue
from tblservice as s join customer as c on s.id = c.id
where (s.Timing)>=DateAdd("d",-30,Date())
group by s.id
```

Comment: Does it give the position of the syntax error?

Comment: Also, what is the exact text of the error message?  Is it the exact same error message for both queries?

Comment: Yup it gives the same error message "Syntax error in FROM clause." nothing more than that, it is again ms access

Comment: Apart from the join problem noted by Remou and Barry, I have noticed that your tblService table doesn't have a field named `id` but one that is named `serviceID`.  
This doesn't seems to be the name of the field that keeps the Foreing Key relationship to the customer table. Is it named tblService.ID ?

Comment: I think your on to something, the foreign key to the customer table is called "customerID". I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select c.id, c.firstname, avg(s.Total) / count(c.id) as LifetimeValue
from tblservice as s inner join customer as c on s.id = c.id
group by c.id, c.firstname
```

and

```
select c.id, c.firstname, avg(s.Total) / count(c.id) as LifetimeValue
from tblservice as s inner join customer as c on s.id = c.id
where (s.Timing)>=DateAdd("d",-30,Date())
group by c.id, c.firstname
```

You cannot select `c.id` and `c.firstname` unless you group by them. And you can use `count(c.id)` since you are already grouping by `c.id`. I have not used SQL in MS Access though. So I am not 100% sure. Try it out.

Comment: hmmm I tried to execute the query but seem to be getting the same syntax error message

Comment: You missed specifying the join type as @Barry Brown mentions.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access may require you to use `INNER JOIN` instead of just `JOIN`.

Comment: I seem to be getting a dialog asking me to enter in the s.id.  I do have many records.  when I put in a record number it only pulls up the average for one record. I'm trying to calculate the average lifetime value of customers in the system.

Comment: Are you grouping by `c.id` and `c.firstname` as @Raze2dust suggested?

Comment: I am and as soon as I run it with the grouping as @Raze2dust suggested I am getting a "Enter Parameter Value" dialog asking me to enter value for s.id